# how to convert data frame to dictionary keeping 1 column as keys and summing the values of second column against each key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

i have a data frame with two columns "authors" and their "ranks". i need to calculate the total rank of each unique author. there are a total of 2.3 million unique authors and the dimension of my current data frame is 13248457,2.
my current solution takes extremely long to execute and i believe dictionaries will quicken the process but i dont know how to use dictionaries.

the following code is how i tried to solve this problem but it will take hours to execute.

```
for auth in unique_auth:
    unique_auth_ranks.append(np.sum(list((df[df.authors == auth ])['rank'])))
```

if i can set the unique_authors as keys to a dictionary and sum their ranks it might work quicker but i have never used dictionaries in python before.

the ranks are numerical values for example an author "abc" occurs 3 times with ranks "1","3" and "5" i want the end result to be "abc": "9"

Comment: `df.groupby('authors')['rank'].sum()`?

Comment: the ranks are numerical values for example an author occurs 3 times with ranks "1","3" and "5" i want the end result to be author name : "8"

Comment: Do you mean "9"?

Comment: sorry i did mean 9

Comment: Have you tried the recommendation by @yatu yet?

Comment: yes this does group authors but it does not seem to return the correct ranks. it seems to be returning the total number of times the author existed.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: your data looks something like:

```
  AuthorName  rank
0    author1     1
1    author2     2
2    author1     3
3    author1     4
4    author3     5
5    author3     6
6    author5     7
7    author3     8
```

And you want:

```
df = df.groupby('AuthorName').sum()
```

which returns:

```
            rank
AuthorName      
author1        8
author2        2
author3       19
author5        7
```

Since `author1` appears with ranks 1,3,4, the resulting rank summation is 8.

Using groupby will be very quick.  Instead of asking pandas to look through the entire data frame for each unique author name (i.e. `df[df.authors == auth ]`), `groupby` will map positional locations for each author name before the data are aggregated.